# value for the annotation attribute must be constant expression

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a properties file that I read by spring annotation like this

```
    @Value("${platform}")
    private String platform;
```

after I get the platform parameter, I would like to read a second parameter depending on `platform` parameter value.

```
    @Value("${url." + platform + ."ws}")
    private String url;
```

but this gives error, "value for the annotation attribute must be constant expression". 
since there are lots of parameter changes depending on "platform" value, I am looking for a generic solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access `platform` directly in the @Value expression, but you can use Spring Expression Language to accomplish your end goal.

```
@Value("${platform}")
private String platform;

@Value("#{'Url.'.concat(${platform}).concat('.ws')}")
private String url;
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is evaluated in compilation time. So it needs to be `final` or `static final` among others (ie `Enum`).

I don't know if the `@Value` annotation allows that. But you can always implement your own annotation. Extending is not possible in Java annotations.

Comment: so is there a way to use first parameter value to get second parameter?

Comment: is there any sample how i can extend @Value annotaion? i am newbie in spring annotaions.

Comment: No it is not possible, but you can use your own annotation.