# The value for annotation attribute AssertTrue.message must be a constant expression

Tags: java, eclipse, validation

The error message keep disallow me to compile my project in eclipse lula. I found this only happen if my util class reading the message from resources bundle, else it is working fine.

Please advise.

Below is my code:

### MessageUtil.java

```
private static final String MSG_FILE = "com.by.go.booking.ui.messages"; 

 private final static ResourceBundle MESSAGE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(MSG_FILE);

 public static final String LOGIN_ID_EXISTS = MESSAGE.getString("ERR1");
```

---

### LoginBean.java

```
@AssertTrue(message = MessageUtil.LOGIN_ID_EXISTS)
public boolean isLoginIdUnique() {
    boolean result = false;
    // validate login ID exists
    ........
    return result;
}
```

---

From the code above, eclipse will trigger the error message:"The value for annotation attribute AssertTrue.message must be a constant expression"

Anyway, if I modify the MessageUtil.java  as below, that is not error in eclipse.

### MessageUtil.java

```
 public static final String LOGIN_ID_EXISTS = "Login is invalid";
```

---

Comment: This just how it is… sorry. It needs to be a _compile time constant_. Maybe someone else can find a post that explains the details on why this is the way it is

Comment: What is the structure of `com.by.go.booking.ui.messages` class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that is the problem, but how can annotation message retrieve the value from file or resources bundle?

Comment: com.by.go.booking.ui.messages is the properties file

Comment: I mean possible if the validation message retrieve from resource bundle as the code below.
-------------
    @AssertTrue(message = <Message get from resources bundle>)
    public boolean isLoginIdUnique() {
        boolean result = false;
        // validate login ID exists
        ........
        return result;
     }
------------

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should the value for an annotation attribute be a constant expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931143/why-should-the-value-for-an-annotation-attribute-be-a-constant-expression)