# The value for annotation attribute FindBy.xpath must be a constant expression

Tags: java, final, properties-file

My problem is different of what has been posted:

1. [value for the annotation attribute must be constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926596/value-for-the-annotation-attribute-must-be-constant-expression) **OR**
2. [The value for annotation attribute Min.value must be a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744067/the-value-for-annotation-attribute-min-value-must-be-a-constant-expression)

I have already made it `final` and `static` still it is giving me that error on hovering over it.

Here is my code:
**Login.java**

```
@FindBy(xpath = Constants.user_email)
public static WebElement user_email;
```

**Constants.java**

```
public static final String user_email= CONFIG.getProperty("user_email");
```

What I tried to fix this:
I changed this `public static Properties CONFIG = new Properties();` to this 
`public static final Properties CONFIG = new Properties();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotation element values must be resolvable by the compiler at compile time.  It is not enough that `user_email` is static final, its value must be a *compile time constant*, i.e. a string literal or a concatenation of constant expressions.  The expression `CONFIG.getProperty("user_email")` is not resolvable until run time, so you can't use it for an annotation value.

The exact definition of "constant expression" is given in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28):

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - Qualified names (§6.5.6.2) of the form TypeName . Identifier that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

Where a "constant variable" is a "variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression"

(yes, these definitions are circular, and in the case of strings you eventually have to bottom out at a quoted string literal or an expression that concatenates a series of other constant expressions).

Comment: SO I can't use `public static final String user_email = CONFIG.getProperty("user_email");` I have to pass value directly like this `public static final String user_email = "//*[@id='user_email']"`. **Or** is there any workaround so that I can pass value using **CONFIG properties file**

Comment: @paul Not if it has to be an annotation.  If you want to use XPaths that are not compile-time constants then you'll have to call the `WebDriver` methods yourself rather than using `PageFactory` annotations.